# Exchange ActiveSync on Android: All flavours of Android are not equals

Tags: email, exchange, active-sync

Just a quick question/remarks regarding the Support of Microsoft Exchange Activesync.

I work in a big company (10.000 people in belgium) and we have to configure an Exchange client to read emails.

iPhones are working fine, and on Android, they suggest to install Touchdown, a third party client with which they have an agreement and we get some discount.

Unfortunately, as I don't want to install third party apps to read email, in addition to gmail and stock email, I have been searching for some explanations.

I have then remarked that all my colleagues with an HTC Sense have a fully working email client!
HTC Seems to have improved the stock email app.

I contacted the HTC customer service but I couldn't get an answer on which ActiveSync features they improved.

Does anyone know if a list of all policies supported by native Android Vs Sense, Touchwozz, Blur.. exists?

I am pretty sure that other people than me are bugged with this issues and would like to compare all these email clients and see wich is the best, maybe some other would be porting Sense email to stock ROM.

Have you any idea of people working on that or other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Porting of Sense apps/widgets to stock Android may not be feasible because of all the framework changes HTC introduces with their overlay.  It's just that by the time you port over all the prerequisites, you end up running Sense anyways.  Not that this hasn't been attempted many times.

Answer (score -1):

The stock email cient is not working after I updated ICS 4.1.2 cyanogenMod 10.  I am using nito desk touchdown and its very reliable.

Comment: Do you have a link to this app?

Answer (score -2):

There is a default AOSP Email.apk that is easy to setup with Exchange---

I suppose you would have to be rooted in order to get the Email.apk into your /system/app
But you can get one from:
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Latest_Version/Google_Apps
and
http://goo.im/gapps/

But you don't necessarily have to be running CM-- just make sure the base version matches up to yours.

Most rooted ROMS come with a good Exchange app--- if you prod around forum.xda-developers.com , you could probably find one that doesn't require root access to install.

Comment: The links you gave are to Google's proprietary apps. Those have nothing to do with exchange. Furthermore the question was asking for a comparison.

Comment: X| 

the proprietary apps work with exchange.
POP3, IMAP, and Exchange~
Push notifications and all. 

I prefer the AOSP to the HTC one. 

Touchdown is OKAY- but it wasn't worth the price- and it's much heavier than it needs to be.